# wordpress post type when save/edit custom message how to shown?

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress post type when save/edit custom message how to shown?

```php
function validate_books($post_id) {
    // Skip post revisions
    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    if ( 'book' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        $choose_books = get_field('choose_books', 'option');
        if (!empty($choose_books) && in_array($post_id, $choose_books)) {
            add_action('admin_notices', 'display_custom_error_message');  
            return;
        }
    }
}

function display_custom_error_message() {
    echo '<div class="error"><p>You cant save this post!</p></div>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'validate_books');
add_action('post_updated', 'validate_books');
```

Comment: Custom post type name: book
Classic editor used. admin_notices hooks not working
add_action('admin_notices', 'display_custom_error_message');

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, in your `validate_books` function remove everything _except_ the `add_action` call, just to see if that's working